# Saving an Object (Data persistence)

Tags: python, serialization, persistence

I've created an object like this:

```
company1.name = 'banana' 
company1.value = 40
```

I would like to save this object. How can I do that?

Comment: See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33245595/562769) for people who come here for a simple example how to use pickle.

Comment: @MartinThoma: Why do you (seemingly) prefer that answer to the accepted one (of the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218477/how-can-i-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict))?

Comment: At the time I linked, the accepted answer did not have `protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`. My answer also gives alternatives to pickle.

Comment: OP never asked to use Pickle for this task; that tag was added years later - by the same person who wrote the accepted answer, contemporary with the question - based on how it was answered. This seems to have inspired the deletion of at least one later answer that was perfectly valid but described other approaches. The `save` tag, meanwhile, is simply useless. At any rate, the question *as asked* is a clear duplicate, and the other version offers other approaches freely.

Answer (score 672, accepted):

You could use the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) module in the standard library.
Here's an elementary application of it to your example:

```
import pickle

class Company(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

with open('company_data.pkl', 'wb') as outp:
    company1 = Company('banana', 40)
    pickle.dump(company1, outp, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    company2 = Company('spam', 42)
    pickle.dump(company2, outp, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

del company1
del company2

with open('company_data.pkl', 'rb') as inp:
    company1 = pickle.load(inp)
    print(company1.name)  # -> banana
    print(company1.value)  # -> 40

    company2 = pickle.load(inp)
    print(company2.name) # -> spam
    print(company2.value)  # -> 42
```

You could also define your own simple utility like the following which opens a file and writes a single object to it:

```
def save_object(obj, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as outp:  # Overwrites any existing file.
        pickle.dump(obj, outp, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# sample usage
save_object(company1, 'company1.pkl')
```

### Update

Since this is such a popular answer, I'd like touch on a few slightly advanced usage topics.

#### `cPickle` (or `_pickle`) vs `pickle`

It's almost always preferable to actually use the [`cPickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) module rather than `pickle` because the former is written in C and is much faster. There are some subtle differences between them, but in most situations they're equivalent and the C version will provide greatly superior performance. Switching to it couldn't be easier, just change the `import` statement to this:

```
import cPickle as pickle
```

In Python 3, `cPickle` was renamed `_pickle`, but doing this is no longer necessary since the `pickle` module now does it automatically—see [What difference between pickle and _pickle in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191859/what-difference-between-pickle-and-pickle-in-python-3).

The rundown is you could use something like the following to ensure that your code will *always* use the C version when it's available in both Python 2 and 3:

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import pickle
```

#### Data stream formats (protocols)

`pickle` can read and write files in several different, Python-specific, formats, called *protocols* as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format), "Protocol version 0" is ASCII and therefore "human-readable". Versions > 0 are binary and the highest one available depends on what version of Python is being used. The default also depends on Python version. In Python 2 the default was Protocol version `0`, but in Python 3.8.1, it's Protocol version `4`. In Python 3.x the module had a `pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL` added to it, but that doesn't exist in Python 2.

Fortunately there's shorthand for writing `pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` in every call (assuming that's what you want, and you usually do), just use the literal number `-1` — similar to referencing the last element of a sequence via a negative index.
So, instead of writing:

```
pickle.dump(obj, outp, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

You can just write:

```
pickle.dump(obj, outp, -1)
```

Either way, you'd only have specify the protocol once if you created a `Pickler` object for use in multiple pickle operations:

```
pickler = pickle.Pickler(outp, -1)
pickler.dump(obj1)
pickler.dump(obj2)
   etc...
```

*Note*: If you're in an environment running different versions of Python, then you'll probably want to explicitly use (i.e. hardcode) a specific protocol number that all of them can read (later versions can generally read files produced by earlier ones).

#### Multiple Objects

While a pickle file *can* contain any number of pickled objects, as shown in the above samples, when there's an unknown number of them, it's often easier to store them all in some sort of variably-sized container, like a `list`, `tuple`, or `dict` and write them all to the file in a single call:

```
tech_companies = [
    Company('Apple', 114.18), Company('Google', 908.60), Company('Microsoft', 69.18)
]
save_object(tech_companies, 'tech_companies.pkl')
```

and restore the list and everything in it later with:

```
with open('tech_companies.pkl', 'rb') as inp:
    tech_companies = pickle.load(inp)
```

The major advantage is you don't need to know how many object instances are saved in order to load them back later (although doing so without that information *is* possible, it requires some slightly specialized code). See the answers to the related question [Saving and loading multiple objects in pickle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716812/saving-and-loading-multiple-objects-in-pickle-file) for details on different ways to do this. Personally I liked @Lutz Prechelt's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28745948/355230) the best, so that's the approach used in the sample code below:

```
class Company:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

def pickle_loader(filename):
    """ Deserialize a file of pickled objects. """
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            try:
                yield pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                break

print('Companies in pickle file:')
for company in pickle_loader('company_data.pkl'):
    print('  name: {}, value: {}'.format(company.name, company.value))
```

Comment: This is rare to me because I imagined there would be a easier way to do save a object... Something like 'saveobject(company1,c:\mypythonobjects)

Comment: @Peterstone: If you only wanted to store one object you would only need about half as much code as in my example -- I purposefully wrote it the way I did to show how more than one object could be saved into (and later read back from) the same file.

Comment: @Peterstone, there is a very good reason for the separation of responsibilities. This way there is no limitation on how the data from the pickling process is being used. You can store it to disc or you could also send it accross a network connection.

Comment: @Harald Scheirich: Could you please elaborate on what you mean about a "separation of responsibilities" -- I'm not exactly sure to what you are referring.

Comment: @martinaeau, this was in response to perstones remark about one should have just one function to save an object to disk. The pickles responsibility is _only_ to turn an object into data that can be handled as a chunk. Writing things to file is the file objects responsibility. By keeping things separate one enables higher reuse e.g. being able to send the pickled data accross a network connection or storing it in a database, all responsibilities separate from the actual data<->object conversion

Comment: @Harald Scheirich: Ah, I see...and agree ;-) but doubt Peterstone is concerned nor able appreciate the finer points of the high level design of the various Python modules and how they fit together at this stage.

Comment: You delete `company1` and `company2`.  Why don't you also delete `Company` and show what happens?

Comment: @Mike: Primarily because doing so has little bearing on the question at hand, nor is it something most folks reading the thread are likely to ever want to do. But also because I strongly suspect the primary motivation for asking it is nothing more than a veiled attempt to publicize the `dill` module you wrote — which certainly sounds like it might come in handy in some situations.

Comment: @martineau: it's not a veiled attempt... when you have a hammer, you find you see that there are nails everywhere.  Anyway... it's a valid point for me to raise… and it has been asked several times on SO.

Comment: @Mike: Sorry, I don't think this question is the right kind of nail. FWIW, I think an effective way to promote `dill` would be to more clearly state what it can do that `pickle` can't on its download page, rather than proposing its use to solve issues unrelated to the problem at hand in various SO posts. If there's a consensus that it adequately addresses serious deficiencies folks are commonly encountering while trying to use `pickle`, perhaps it should be made part of the standard library.

Comment: @martineau: I disagree.  Look at the question. It's a pretty strong assumption to assume that the object the OP is asking about is a class.  If it's not a class, then `pickle` will fail you in most cases.  My answer is a more general one, thus the right type of nail.  I was picking at a scab a bit in the comments of your answer, but it's still in my opinion a valid point.  You have every right to disagree.  …and I'm not really trying to promote `dill`, I'm just answering the question with all the tools I have in my toolbox.

Comment: What is if i create my objects in a for loop (because of different parameter combinations). The have to be named in a different way to get later acess to it, isnt it. And if yes, then how could i create different names for my objects in a for loop?

Comment: @Varlor: You could create different names by defining a counter that is initialized just before entering the `for` loop, and then inside it to generate each filename. i.e. `filename = 'myname{}.pkl'.format(count)`, followed by `count += 1`. However it would probably be better to put all the objects in a list and `pickle.dump()` it, which will save all of them at once in a single file and preserve the order they appear in the list. You can also put them in a dictionary and `dump()` that.

Comment: @martineau: You promote the idea to use pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL. But isn't that a bit risky in the longer term? If you store your object in format version x from Python 3.6 but way later switch to a newer version of Python where pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL refers to format version x+1 then you might not be able anymore to load your data, right?
This is why I think it would be better to consciously choose the currently highest version. Then you can update Python and still migrate the format later.

Comment: Or is the version used to store the object(s) part of the data so the reading process knows the version and can always load the data with the correct version?

Comment: @Sandro: Yes, the protocol used is stored in the file. _Later_ versions should be able to read a files produced by a previous versions. In an environment where a mixture of Python versions are being used, what you say makes sense. I "promoted" the use of `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` because it generally is going to produce the smallest (and probably the fastest) results.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the answer, that's very good to know! Others might wonder about that aspect as well so you could touch on that in your answer if you want.

Comment: @Sandro: Added a little something about it to the **Data stream formats** section.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative answer! Just one thing; what is the `save_object` function you are using?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: It's defined near the beginning of the answer.

Answer (score 74):

I think it's a pretty strong assumption to assume that the object is a `class`. What if it's not a `class`?  There's also the assumption that the object was not defined in the interpreter.  What if it was defined in the interpreter?  Also, what if the attributes were added dynamically? When some python objects have attributes added to their `__dict__` after creation, `pickle` doesn't respect the addition of those attributes (i.e. it 'forgets' they were added -- because `pickle` serializes by reference to the object definition).

In all these cases, `pickle` and `cPickle` can fail you horribly.

If you are looking to save an `object` (arbitrarily created), where you have attributes (either added in the object definition, or afterward)… your best bet is to use `dill`, which can serialize almost anything in python.

We start with a class…

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> class Company:
...     pass
... 
>>> company1 = Company()
>>> company1.name = 'banana'
>>> company1.value = 40
>>> with open('company.pkl', 'wb') as f:
...     pickle.dump(company1, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
... 
>>>
```

Now shut down, and restart...

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('company.pkl', 'rb') as f:
...     company1 = pickle.load(f)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1126, in find_class
    klass = getattr(mod, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Company'
>>>
```

Oops… `pickle` can't handle it.  Let's try `dill`.  We'll throw in another object type (a `lambda`) for good measure.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill       
>>> class Company:
...     pass
... 
>>> company1 = Company()
>>> company1.name = 'banana'
>>> company1.value = 40
>>> 
>>> company2 = lambda x:x
>>> company2.name = 'rhubarb'
>>> company2.value = 42
>>> 
>>> with open('company_dill.pkl', 'wb') as f:
...     dill.dump(company1, f)
...     dill.dump(company2, f)
... 
>>>
```

And now read the file.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> with open('company_dill.pkl', 'rb') as f:
...     company1 = dill.load(f)
...     company2 = dill.load(f)
... 
>>> company1 
<__main__.Company instance at 0x107909128>
>>> company1.name
'banana'
>>> company1.value
40
>>> company2.name
'rhubarb'
>>> company2.value
42
>>>
```

It works. The reason `pickle` fails, and `dill` doesn't, is that `dill` treats `__main__` like a module (for the most part), and also can pickle class definitions instead of pickling by reference (like `pickle` does).  The reason `dill` can pickle a `lambda` is that it gives it a name… then pickling magic can happen.

Actually, there's an easier way to save all these objects, especially if you have a lot of objects you've created.  Just dump the whole python session, and come back to it later.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> class Company:
...     pass
... 
>>> company1 = Company()
>>> company1.name = 'banana'
>>> company1.value = 40
>>> 
>>> company2 = lambda x:x
>>> company2.name = 'rhubarb'
>>> company2.value = 42
>>> 
>>> dill.dump_session('dill.pkl')
>>>
```

Now shut down your computer, go enjoy an espresso or whatever, and come back later...

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> dill.load_session('dill.pkl')
>>> company1.name
'banana'
>>> company1.value
40
>>> company2.name
'rhubarb'
>>> company2.value
42
>>> company2
<function <lambda> at 0x1065f2938>
```

The only major drawback is that `dill` is not part of the python standard library. So if you can't install a python package on your server, then you can't use it.

However, if you are able to install python packages on your system, you can get the latest `dill` with `git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill.git@master#egg=dill`. And you can get the latest released version with `pip install dill`.

Comment: I'm getting a `TypeError: __new__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` when trying to use `dill` (which looks promising) with a rather complex object that includes an audio file.

Comment: @MikeiLL: You are getting a `TypeError` when you do what, exactly?  That's usually a sign of having the wrong number of arguments when instantiating a class instance.  If this is not part of the workflow of the above question, could you post it as another question, submit it to me over email, or add it as an issue on the `dill` github page?

Comment: For anyone following along, here's the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538812/python-typeerror-on-load-object-using-dill) @MikeLL posted -- from the answer, it apparently wasn't a `dill` issue.

Comment: `dil`l gives me `MemoryError` though! so does `cPickle`, `pickle` and `hickle`.

Comment: During read operation I am getting following error for dill `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` would it be possible to over come this?

Comment: @alper: you are getting a RecursionError for the above example, or for something else?  Best to post a new question and refer to this one if the code is related.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I was getting it for much complex object

Comment: A `RecursionError` is a known result for some objects.  Maybe you've found one of those cases. Post a new SO question, or open a GitHub issue if you want help.

Answer (score 18):

Quick example using `company1` from your question, with python3.

```py
import pickle

# Save the file
pickle.dump(company1, file = open("company1.pickle", "wb"))

# Reload the file
company1_reloaded = pickle.load(open("company1.pickle", "rb"))
```

However, as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30720219/4745348) noted, pickle often fails. So you should really use `dill`.

```py
import dill

# Save the file
dill.dump(company1, file = open("company1.pickle", "wb"))

# Reload the file
company1_reloaded = dill.load(open("company1.pickle", "rb"))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [anycache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/anycache) to do the job for you. It considers all the details:

- It uses [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) as backend,
  which extends the python `pickle` module to handle `lambda` and all the nice
  python features.
- It stores different objects to different files and reloads them properly.
- Limits cache size
- Allows cache clearing
- Allows sharing of objects between multiple runs
- Allows respect of input files which influence the result

Assuming you have a function `myfunc` which creates the instance:

```
from anycache import anycache

class Company(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

@anycache(cachedir='/path/to/your/cache')    
def myfunc(name, value)
    return Company(name, value)
```

Anycache calls `myfunc` at the first time and pickles the result to a
file in `cachedir` using an unique identifier (depending on the function name and its arguments) as filename.
On any consecutive run, the pickled object is loaded.
If the `cachedir` is preserved between python runs, the pickled object is taken from the previous python run.

For any further details see the [documentation](http://anycache.readthedocs.io)

Comment: How would one use `anycache` to save more than one instance of, say, a `class` or container such as a `list` (that wasn't the result of calling a function)?

Answer (score 4):

Newer versions of pandas has also a functionality to save pickles.

I find it easier. e.g.

```
pd.to_pickle(object_to_save,'/temp/saved_pkl.pickle' )
```

Answer (score 2):

While `pickle` is the most widely used option for serialising objects, it's not without its concerns, especially regarding security. It's possible to construct a Python object that, when deserialised, will execute arbitrary code. An example is included below.

```
import pickle

class Example:
    def __reduce__(self):
        print("Serialised")
        return print, ("Deserialised",)

example = Example()

serialised = pickle.dumps(example) # prints "Serialised"
pickle.loads(serialised) # prints "Deserialised"
```

While the above example is perfectly harmless, it would be trivial to make it much, much nastier, for example by replacing `print` with `exec` or `eval` in the return value.

There isn't really a good solution to this, but people have mentioned the `dill` library as a possible alternative to `pickle`. There is, however, another alternative, `marshal`. It's a builtin serialisation library, but it has the drawback that it doesn't work on some kinds of object (though, unlike `pickle`, it can serialise CodeObjects, which is why it is internally used to serialise the aforementioned during compilation of CodeObjects into `.pyc` files). It's also much faster, being in C ([code here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/marshal.c)), but hasn't been rigorously audited. However, no security vulnerabilities are known.

`marshal` is effectively a drop-in replacement for `pickle`. The `loads`, `load`, `dumps` and `dump` methods all do exactly the same thing.