# I am trying to build a knowledge management system that learns dynamically. As it comes

Tags: python, class, serialization, dynamic, persistence

I am trying to build a knowledge management system that in small way tries to mimic human ability to learn. It deals with both, new instances of concepts that it already knows, which allows it to further improve/specialize the knowledge base for the known concept(s). It can also learn new concepts that it has never encountered before. When it encounters new concepts it creates relationships with existing concepts. I am thinking that the native object oriented paradigm of a programming language itself could be an ideal data model for knowledge representation. For example *classes* are concepts (things) which has *attributes* that describe the concept and *methods* that describe how it (concept/thing) interacts. Hence a car is a generic concept hence modelled as a *class* while my specific car would be an *object* instance of that car. It obviously benefit from inheritance and up/down navigation ability provided by object oriented languages in dealing with classes and objects. Given the strong dynamic nature of Python, I am planning on using it for this purpose.

Couple of implications of such a learning system are,

1. Since the system learns new things about concepts (classes and objects) it already knows, it will have to modify the definition of classes dynamically by adding/deleting attributes (including methods) in addition to changing attribute values, thus a static definition of classes won't suffice. Methods are especially tricky since there is code associated with them.
2. As it encounters new concepts it would have to create new classes dynamically.
3. Each time the system starts it should start with all the prior knowledge loaded into the system for the obvious reason. In this case it means all the "current" versions (including any added/deleted or changed attributes/values/methods) of all knowledge classes (including dynamically created ones) i.e. a fairly comprehensive serialization/persistence mechanism is required.

At the end of the session (tear-down), it would have to look at "all" knowledge classes and objects and serialize them. Some might have gotten defined newly, some might have changed their attributes or even methods (codes). Need a way to get all these objects/classes, their most up to date definition and serialize them for persistence.

Next time the system runs, during initialization, it needs to read and execute all the class definitions and restore the state of object instances.

I have looked around and found piecemeal solutions such as pickle, json, ZODB, inspect module etc. but none seem to be able to serialize dynamic classes including code for the methods.

A similar question was asked here [Python: saving and loading a class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574053/python-saving-and-loading-a-class-definition)
but most respondents thought that there wasn't any compelling use-case for this.

Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quick note: python class and object attributes are modifiable at runtime. `a = Foo(); a.new_attr = "New attribute added"` is prefectly OK.

Comment: @msvalkon Thanks. I am aware of that. In fact you can add new methods and create new classes with type() meta class on the fly. Not sure if you can add to the inheritance list on the fly though. Would be useful when later the system learns a new fact about the concept which requires it to additionally inherit from another class.

Comment: Referring to my previous comment directed at mvsvalkon, there is an additional implication/issue. If a class definition changes dynamically to include additional inheritance, what would happen to all derived (directly/indirectly) classes? would their mro be adjusted accordingly?

Comment: adding attributes on the fly like that only affects that particular object and will not apply to the class definition. I was trying to point out that this sort of dynamic behaviour is built-in and perhaps you or someone else can find a way to build from that.