# Python: Saving dictionary to .py file

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary

I have got a dictionary `this_dict` produced in a python script that I would like to write to a separate python module `dict_file.py`. This would allow me to load the dictionary in another script by importing `dict_file`.

I thought a possible way of doing this was using JSON, so I used the following code:

```
import json

this_dict = {"Key1": "Value1",
             "Key2": "Value2",
             "Key3": {"Subkey1": "Subvalue1",
                      "Subkey2": "Subvalue2"
                     }
            }

with open("dict_file.py", "w") as dict_file:
    json.dump(this_dict, dict_file, indent=4)
```

When I opened the resulting file in my editor, I got a nicely printed dictionary. However, the name of the dictionary in the script (`this_dict`) was not included in the generated `dict_file.py` (so only the braces and the body of the dictionary were written). How can I include the name of the dictionary too?
I want it to generate `dict_file.py` as follows:

```
this_dict = {"Key1": Value1,
             "Key2": Value2,
             "Key3": {"Subkey1": Subvalue1,
                      "Subkey2": Subvalue2
                     }
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/pickle.html) instead?

Comment: Seems easier to just load the file as json `this_dict = json.load(open("dict_file.json"))` instead of generating source code.

Comment: 2nd the usage of **pickle** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530611/saving-and-loading-objects-and-using-pickle

Comment: Dictionaries don't have names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) use file.write:

```
file.write('this_dict = ')
json.dump(this_dict, dict_file)
```

2) use write + json.dumps, which returns a string with json:

```
file.write('this_dict = ' + json.dumps(this_dict)
```

3) just print it, or use repr

```
file.write('this_dict = ')
file.write(repr(this_dict))
# or:
# print(this_dict, file=file)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) as @roganjosh proposed in the comments, a hacky workaround would be the following:

```
this_dict = {"Key1": "Value1",
             "Key2": "Value2",
             "Key3": {"Subkey1": "Subvalue1",
                      "Subkey2": "Subvalue2"
                     }
            }

# print the dictionary instead
print 'this_dict = '.format(this_dict)
```

And execute the script as:

```
python myscript.py > dict_file.py
```

**Note:** Of course this assumes that you will not have any other print statements on `myscript.py`.