# Modify a list saved in a .txt file

Tags: python, list, file

I have a list of this form in a `.txt` file: `student1, 2, 3 | student2, 1, 4`
I need to call it in a program, add `[student3, 3, 5]` to the list, and then save it back into the `.txt` file. I did this but my list looked like this at the end: `[[''], ['Student3', '3', '5']]`

```
f = open('classe1.txt','r')
liste = f.read()
liste = liste.split('|')
n = len(liste)
for i in range (n):
    liste[i] = liste[i].split(',')
liste.append(['Student3','3','5'])
liste = str(liste)

f = open('classe1.txt','w')
f.write(liste)
```

How would you do it ? 
Thank you !

Comment: Please post a sample of the actual txt file and the desired result.

Comment: student1, 2, 3 | student2, 1, 4

Comment: I tried to write it [[student1, 2, 3], [student2, 1, 4]] originally

Comment: how should be your desired output looks like?

Comment: what do you need on the final txt file.

Comment: I tried to run it and the code works fine. It prints ```[['student1', ' 2', ' 3 '], [' student2', ' 1', ' 4'], ['Student3', '3', '5']]```. Check this link : http://tpcg.io/0Z3bGa

Comment: The result would be anything that could then be changed in python into a list of this form: [[student1, 2, 3],[ student2, 1, 4],[student3, 3, 5]]

Comment: Yes Sandesh, only the problem is I cant write a list, so I had to change liste to str(liste) before I wrote it. Sorry I forgot that part

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood your question correctly, but to append a string to a text file, you can use `a`, i.e.:

```
with open("classe1.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("| student3, 3, 5 ")
```

---

If you need to write a python `object` to a file, you can use [json load and dump](http://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/) or [Pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530611/saving-and-loading-objects-and-using-pickle).

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, it won't work. I really havn't been clear, sorry. In fact I am making a facial recognition device that makes acquaintance for the teachers. The list is a class, and I would like the teacher to have the ability to add or erase a student in the list and directly from the program. Your solution is much simpler to add a student, but I dont see how to erase one with it.

Comment: You'll probably need to create a database and an interface to manage the records. Your question originally doesn't mention anything about this. You may want to create a new question.

Comment: Yes I havn't been clear, sorry. I'll see what I can find about databases and python on google, and if I still struggle I'll ask another question. Thanks (and sorry) !