# How to decode/read Flask filesystem session files?

Tags: python, caching, flask, werkzeug, flask-session

I have a Python3 Flask app using [Flask-Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) (which adds server-side session support) and configured to use the `filesystem` type.

This type underlying uses the Werkzeug class `werkzeug.contrib.cache.FileSystemCache` ([Werkzeug cache documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.14.x/contrib/cache/)).

The raw cache files look like this if opened:

```
J¬».].Äï;}î(å
_permanentîàå
respondentîåuuidîåUUIDîìî)Åî}î(åintîät˙ò∑ﬂŒºçLÃ/∆6jhåis_safeîhåSafeUUIDîìîNÖîRîubåSECTIONS_VISITEDî]îåcurrent_sectionîKåSURVEY_CONTENTî}î(å0î}î(ås_idîås0îånameîåWelcomeîådescriptionîåîå   questionsî]î}î(ås_idîhåq_idîhåq_constructîhåq_textîhå
q_descriptionîhåq_typeîhårequiredîhåoptions_rowîhåoptions_row_alpha_sortîhåreplace_rowîhåoptions_colîhåoptions_col_codesîhåoptions_col_alpha_sortîhåcond_continue_rules_rowîhåq_meta_notesîhuauå1î}î(hås1îhå    Screeningîhå[This section determines if you fit into the target group.îh]î(}î(hh/håq1îh hh!å9Have you worked on a product in this field before?
```

The items stored in the session can be seen a bit above: 
- `current_section` should be an integer, e.g., `0`
- `SECTIONS_VISITED` should be an array of integers, e.g., `[0,1,2]`
- `SURVEY_CONTENT` format should be an object with structure like below

```
{
  'item1': {
    'label': string,
    'questions': [{}]
  }, 
  'item2': {
    'label': string,
    'questions': [{}]
  }
}
```

What you can see in the excerpt above, for example the text `This section determines if you fit into the target group` is the value of one label. The stuff after `questions` are keys that can be found in each `questions` object, e.g., `q_text` as well as their values, e.g., `Have you worked on a product in this field before?` is the value of `q_text`.

I need to retrieve data from the stored cache files in a way that I can read them without all the extra characters like `å`.

I tried using Werkzeug like this, where the item `9c3c48a94198f61aa02a744b16666317` is the name of the cache file I want to read. However, it was not found in the cache directory.

```
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import FileSystemCache
cache_dir="flask_session"
mode=0600
threshold=20000
cache = FileSystemCache(cache_dir, threshold=threshold, mode=mode)
item = "9c3c48a94198f61aa02a744b16666317"
print(cache.has(item))
data = cache.get(item)
print(data)
```

What ways are there to read the cache files?

I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session/issues/104) in Flask-Session, but that's not really been actively maintained in years.

For context, I had an instance where for my web app writing to the database was briefly not working - but the data I need was also being saved in the session. So right now the only way to retrieve that data is to get it from these files.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Tim's answer I solved it using the following:

```
import pickle
obj = []
with open(file_name,"rb") as fileOpener:
    while True:
        try:
            obj.append(pickle.load(fileOpener))
        except EOFError:
            break
print(obj)
```

I needed to load all pickled objects in the file, so I combined Tim's solution with the one here for loading multiple objects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49261333/11805662

Without this, I was just seeing the first pickled item.

Also, in case anyone has the same problem, I needed to use the same python version as my Flask app ([related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843698/valueerror-unsupported-pickle-protocol-3-python2-pickle-can-not-load-the-file)). If I didn't, then I would get the following error:

```
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 4
```

Comment: The file is the data `pickled`. See https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/0.15.x/src/werkzeug/contrib/cache.py#L803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the data with pickle. Pickle is part of the Python standard library.

```py
import pickle

with open("PATH/TO/SESSION/FILE") as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```