# Accessing the nth pickle in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have a file with thousands of `pickle` objects.
I want to access the nth pickled object without having to load all of the preceding objects.
I checked the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463387/pickle-putting-more-than-1-object-in-a-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716812/saving-and-loading-multiple-objects-in-pickle-file) but they don't answer my question. My understanding is that recursive unpickling starts at the top and moves the cursor to the next item after each item is unpickled.

Is it possible to manually specify where the cursor should start so I only unpickle the objects I want?

e.g.

```
import pickle

with open('file.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    for _ in range(2000, 2005):
        data = pickle.load(f) # This only loads the first 5 items, not the 2000-2005th items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a new project, use the "shelve" module instead. You can access the pickled objects dictionary-like:

```
import shelve

sh= shelve.open("my_objects.db")
ll= [1,2,3,"Hello"]
sh["my_list"]= ll
sh["my_dict"]= { k:k*10 for k in range(10) }
sh.close()

sh= shelve.open("my_objects.db")
lizy= sh["my_list"]
dizy= sh["my_dict"]
sh.close()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and doesn't help people who aren't starting a new project.