# How to add data to a list in the code while running

Tags: python

Suppose i want to add something to

```
list = []
```

such that the value of list gets updated in the code it self.
In runtime: 
list gets modified to

```
list =['hello','Dude']
```

How can i do so?

What i mean is, that there are real changes made to the List value in the .py file.

Comment: The [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) explains lots of basic stuff like this

Comment: I would not recommend attempting to do this. It is better to separate code and data completely, and for example store your data in a `json` file that you read in, for example like this: `list = json.load(open('data.json'))` (Of course you need to `import json`). You can write it similarly: `json.dump(list, open('data.json', 'wb'))`

Answer (score 2):

Just use append where ever you need it:

```
list = []
list.append('hello')
print list
list.append('Dude')
print list
```

Output:

```
['hello']
['hello', 'Dude']<
```

---

Easy way would be to create additional file and to store variables there.

**Code:**

```
list = []
f = open("list.txt", "r+")
for item in f:
    list.append(str(item).rstrip())

f.write("Something")
f.close()
```

**list.txt:**

```
hello
Dude
```

**list.txt after execution:**

```
hello
Dude
Something
```

Comment: No. What i mean is. If in the code i have List = ''. After runtime the code changes to some List = ['hi','there']

Comment: Post code that you have

Comment: I will begin making the code once you tell me  how to make real changes to the .py file from the code.

Comment: I am confused... do you want to edit the list or do you want to edit your .py script in another .py script?

Comment: I want to edit some List value in the .py script so that whatever i add remains permanent, and the next time i run the script, i can work with whatever my List had from the first run of the program.

Comment: You don't realize data persistence by modifying the code. Save the data to a data file and load it if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your comments to one of the other answers what you are looking for is a way to serialize and save an object to a file so you can reload it once you re-run the program. This is done using [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

An example of this can be found on stack overflow: [How to save an object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/how-to-save-an-object-in-python):

```
import pickle

try:
    with open('list.pk', 'rb') as input:
        list = pickle.load(input)
except:
    list = []

list.append('something')
print(list)

with open('list.pk', 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(list, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it is rewriting the `.py` file.

You don't really want to do that even if it's indeed technically possible.

You should instead keep your data in a separate file, loaded when starting the program and saved back when exiting.

There are special modules for storing python values like e.g. [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html).

A very common alternative is storing the data in a format that can be understood even by other languages intead of python objects, e.g. in a relational database like [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite#sqlite3).