# What difference between pickle and _pickle in python 3?

Tags: python, serialization, python-3.x

I am new in python and want implement **fast** object serialization. I was trying to use json, but it was too slow, also was trying to use marshall module, but the size of the objects serialized by marshall 6-7 times more than pickle, so i decided to use pickle in my project. I read about cPickle module, read that it quite fast, but there is no such module in python 3 and docs says that module named _pickle is written in C. So in my projects i use

```
import _pickle as pickle
```

Is any difference between pickle and _pickle? How i can implement faster objects serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `pickle` module **already** imports `_pickle` if available. It is the C-optimized version of the `pickle` module, and is used transparently.

From the [`pickle.py` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5b22dd87aa39087f07987f788a0bbd2464e2a8b5/Lib/pickle.py#L1348-L1352):

```
# Use the faster _pickle if possible
try:
    from _pickle import *
except ImportError:
    Pickler, Unpickler = _Pickler, _Unpickler
```

and from the [`pickle` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#performance):

> The `pickle` module has an transparent optimizer (`_pickle`) written in C. It is used whenever available. Otherwise the pure Python implementation is used.

In Python 2, `_pickle` was known as `cPickle`, but has been updated to allow the transparent use as an implementation detail.

Comment: So python3 pickle == python2 cPickle?

Comment: note that in addition to it being unnecessary to import _pickle directly in Python 3, it lacks some features such as the .HIGHEST_PROTOCOL constant.

Comment: If I do `import pickle` in Python 2.7.6, which implementation will I get?

Comment: @Moberg: you get the pure-Python implementation. Use `try: import cPickle as pickle`, `except ImportError: import pickle`, to use the C-accelerated implementation if available.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Quick answer, thanks! So I can do a try/except ImportError to support C implementation for both python2 and python3 during a transition period.

Answer (score 12):

From the [Library Changes](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#library-changes) section of the [*What's New In Python 3.0*](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#what-s-new-in-python-3-0) documentation:

> A common pattern in Python 2.x is to have one version of a module
>   implemented in pure Python, with an optional accelerated version
>   implemented as a C extension; for example, `pickle` and `cPickle`. This
>   places the burden of importing the accelerated version and falling
>   back on the pure Python version on each user of these modules. In
>   Python 3.0, the accelerated versions are considered implementation
>   details of the pure Python versions. **Users should always import the
>   standard version, which attempts to import the accelerated version and
>   falls back to the pure Python version. The `pickle` / `cPickle` pair
>   received this treatment.** The profile module is on the list for 3.1.
>   The `StringIO` module has been turned into a class in the io module.

Since it is a python convention that implementation details are prepended with an underscore, `cPickle` became `_pickle`.  Notably this means that if you are importing `_pickle`, the API has no guaranteed contract and *could* break backwards-compatibility in future releases of python3, as unlikely as that may be.