# Deserialisation "pickle" file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-unicode

My code is:

```
import _pickle
with open('items_10000_matrix.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data_new = _pickle.load(f)
```

But an error occurs:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 212: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am using windows 10 + python 3.5 with VS tools for python.

Comment: You say doing an `import pickle` fails - how exactly does it fail? You shouldn't be/need to be using `_pickle`...

Comment: @NinjaPuppy Sorry, it doesnt fail any more, that were just my previus manipulations...

Comment: @martineau Sorry, but: **a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

Comment: @NinjaPuppy I'am sorry, but the problem remains to be, sir.

Comment: OK, try using `_pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')`.

Comment: @martineau: You should never need to open in text mode when reading pickles. Opening `"rb"` is *the* correct way to open a file you'll be unpickling from. I want to know how the original data was pickled here; if it's a legal pickle, written correctly, `open`ing `"rb"` and calling `pickle.load` (`_pickle` is the accelerator `pickle` wraps; never use it directly) should work.

Comment: @martineau It seems to end with no errors. But how am i supposed to work with that file - just like as i have encoded it from ASCII? I am asking, because iam not able to print it.

Comment: @Vladislav: Not sure what you mean by "work with that file" — it's a pickle file and now you have successfully opened and deserialized the object(s) in it (and automatically closed it via the `with`). What more do you want to do with it, `print(data_new)` perhaps?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: My mistake, I was thinking of csv files in Python 3.

Comment: @martineau Is that so?  When i open this file, i can see, that it hadn't changed at all. Sorry, if i cant understand something, but working with othe f.formats was quite easy, opposite to this one.

Comment: @Vladislav: The only thing a pickle file is really good for is storing pickled data that can be read back later. You can store multiple items in one, but unless they are all within some sort of container object, such as a list or dictionary, you will have to unpickle (load) each one separately. See this [answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence-in-python/4529901#4529901) for some examples.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Could you, please, place your answer, so i can mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told to use python 2 instead of python 3, and it worked. Still dont know the solution for python3

Answer (score 0):

Try using `_pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')`.

By the way, in Python 3, there's no reason to explicitly import `_pickle` rather than `pickle` because it will automatically switch to the C version if it's available. See the accepted answer to the question [*What difference between pickle and _pickle in python 3?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191859/what-difference-between-pickle-and-pickle-in-python-3)

Comment: Vladislav: I feel un-accepting my answer was a little unfair. I might have suggested switching to Python 2 if you hadn't explicitly stated you were using python 3.5 (and tagged your question Python-3.x). It's also fairly unusual for someone to be able to easily switch from one to other just like that.