# Weird _pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated

Tags: python, pickle

I've got this error message and I don't get its meaning.

```
_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

My program is using multiprocessing and is running on a workstation with 8 cores and 128 Gb of RAM.

I pickle a list of objects (objects I define in another file), and this list can be quite huge (Several 100 000 of thousands of tuples at best), but also empty.

The way I pickle the data is the following:

```
import _pickle as pickle

with open(join(folder, file), "wb") as output:
    pickle.dump(L, output, -1) # L is the list
```

And I read them like this:

```
with open(join(folder, file), "rb") as input:
    L = pickle.load(input)
```

I've been using this for a while, and that's the first time the program is throwing this error.

Comment: Why arg -1 while dumping?

Comment: If I recall correctly that's for `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`

Comment: Was the data exceptionally large this time compared to past runs?

Comment: @EdwardMinnix Definitely not, I'd say a few thousand items top. Larger I handled was a several million item list (once), took a few hours, and 80 Gb of RAM.

Comment: What does this error mean, and what can cause it?

Comment: That error is caused by the `void bad_readline();` function in the C source whenever it cannot proceed with reading the document. Are you sure nothing is overwriting the file? Because that error signifies that the pickled byte-string is incomplete, like if you forgot a closing `"` or `}` in a JSON document.

Comment: It should not, but there is a slight risk than another process has accessed the file to read it when it was being written by another process... However proba was so low that I didn't implemented the safety, might be the reason...

Comment: I just read in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19191885/9059420) that `_pickle` lacks the `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` constant. Maybe try without this "-1" or just straightly import `pickle` in case you're using python 3.