# Can't load Python 2.x .dat file using _pickle in Python 3.6

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to load a .dat file (RML2016_10b.dat) radio dataset from [DeepSig](https://www.deepsig.io/datasets) using `_pickle` in Python 3.6 as follows:

```
from _pickle import load, dump
Xd = load(open("RML2016_10b.dat", 'rb'))
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anoir/PycharmProjects/AMC/classification.py", line 14, in <module>
    Xd = load(open("RML2016_10b.dat", 'rb'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Might be the case that the file was created with python2. Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218466/unpickling-a-python-2-object-with-python-3

Comment: yes but i cannot use python 2 because i have to use tensorflow which does not work with python 2

Comment: Read the answer: d = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')

Comment: yes i am trying it now ... i just  wanted to explain

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **H4Kor** the from _pickle import load, dump

```
from _pickle import load, dump
Xd = load(open("RML2016_10b.dat", 'rb'), encoding='latin1')
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly `import _pickle` in Python 3. See [What difference between pickle and _pickle in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191859/what-difference-between-pickle-and-pickle-in-python-3)