# How to store an instance of a Class into a file

Tags: python, class, for-loop

This has been bugging me for a while. I can't find anything online that gives me an answer I am looking for. Hopefully you guys canshed some light on this:

Here is a piece of code:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.age = 0
        self.gender = ''


me = MyClass()
me.name = "john"
me.age = 23
me.gender = "male"

with open('MyFile', 'w') as f:
    dict = vars(me)
    for attr in dict:
        f.write(att + '\n')
```

Output:

```
name
age
gender
```

How i want the output to be like...

```
name: john
age: 23
gender: male
```

the format doesn't matter, but something where I can store an instance of a class in a file to be able to read from again.. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You want to read about serializers https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html

Comment: There are so many different ways to do this. Should the file be human-readable? Consider e.g. a JSON representation. If not, `pickle` is probably the lowest-effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4529815/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pickle!

```
#save
file_handler = open("myfile.pkl", "w")
pickle.dump(me, file_handler)

#load
file_handler = open("myfile.pkl", "r")
me = pickle.load(file_handler)
```

Comment: I can't give more than one argument when i do pickle.load?

Comment: You can pickle a list or dictionary of picklable objects. Or just one object.

Answer (score 0):

You could roll your own, or you could try [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html).  This question has been answered before though.

Comment: can you please provide a link, I haven't been able to find anything online that solves this. Maybe I am wording my question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should try pickle, but I think what you are looking for is just to make your code

```
with open('MyFile', 'w') as f:
    dict = vars(me)
    for attr in dict:
        f.write( attr + ': ' + str( dict[attr] ) + '\n')
```

Comment: thank you yes that is was I am looking for, although I will try to go into pickle, because these things are going to be stored to be read from again.