# Python: Can you Save an Object and all of it's Associated Values?

Tags: database, save, load

I have an 2D-Array of co-ordinates that has an arbitrary number of factors to each co-ordinate. (Some have associated Boolean values, String values etc.)

Is there any way, to save the array and all of it's associated values - So that i can just load it up, on any arbitrary ocassion?

I also wish for the solution to be Compatible with Compilation.

I am using Python 2.7 and I have tried cPickle, Shelve, Dill, and jsonpickle.

Comment: When I Google `Python: Can you Save an Object and all of it's Associated Values?` there's a SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/how-to-save-an-object-in-python does that not help? (I don't know Python)

Comment: I have read that post - It covers Pickle and Dill.

The issue, as far as i understand it, is that Pickle cannot save Instanciated values of a Class or an Object.

This is problematic for me, as that would mean, that i would have to specifically assign save values to every single co-ordinate, and every single instance.

Which, sadly, is not very fesible.