# Save data to disk to avoid re-computation

Tags: python, save, hard-drive

I'm a beginner with Python, but I'm at the final stages of a project I've been working on for the past year and I need help at the final step.

If needed I'll post my code though it's not really relevant.

Here is my problem:

I have a database of images, say for example a 100 images. On each one of those images, I run an algorithm called ICA. This algorithm is very heavy to compute and each picture individually usually takes 7-10 seconds, so 100 pictures can take 700-1000 seconds, and that's way too long to wait.

Thing is, my database of images never changes. I never add pictures or delete pictures, and so the output of the ICA algorithm is always the same. So in reality, every time I run my code, I wait forever and gain the same output every time.

Is there a way to save the data to the hard disk, and extract it at a later time?

Say, I compute the ICA of the 100 images, it takes forever, and I save it and close my computer. Now when I run the program, I don't want it to recompute ICA, I want it to use the values I stored previously.

Would such a thing be possible in Python? if so - how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving an Object (Data persistence in Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence-in-python). You can read about Pickling in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). There's a whole section in there about data persistence you can check out.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're running computation-heavy algorithms, I'm going to assume you're using Numpy. If not, you [should be](http://technicaldiscovery.blogspot.ca/2011/06/speeding-up-python-numpy-cython-and.html).

Numpy has a `numpy.save()` function that lets you save arrays in binary format. You can then load them using `numpy.load()`.

EDIT: Docs for aforementioned functions can be found [here](http://technicaldiscovery.blogspot.ca/2011/06/speeding-up-python-numpy-cython-and.html) under the "NPZ Files" section.

Comment: I am using Numpy. By arrays you mean matrices as well? Ill check the docs