# Python: Save objects in a file

Tags: python, class, object, serialization

I have defined this class:

```
class User():
 def __init__(self, ip, update, priority):
    self.ip = ip
    self.update = update
    self.priority = priority
```

I work with a Socket and every time one client is connect I create an User object. I would like to save it somewhere and then be able to process its data, meaning read the file where it's saved.
I don't know how to do that. I tried using a txt file but with the fields of the class User is to complicated and I would also like to have something more dynamic, like

```
add(user), isPresent(user), overwrite(user)
```

What is the best solution for my case?

Comment: either connect to a database or use pickle and put your info in a dictionary that you can save and read to update

Comment: Do you have any example using a database?

Comment: not really - that is more complicated but there are example on-line, try google "python database"

Comment: There is very complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence/4529901).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your User class is really that simple, you can use Pickle:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

(both Python 2 and 3 links included).

```
 u = User(127.0.0.1, "foo", "bar")
 pickle.dumps(u)
```

Comment: Thanks. What does it happen if I save twice the same object? There will be only one or two entities?

Comment: @m.ridolfi - as far as I know, Pickle should be idempotent. So saving the same object multiple times will have the same result. Now, of course, you have to *pick* where to save the object (a text file, to a database, whatever), so if you're asking can you *physically* save the same object twice, that's entirely up to you.