# Dump bytes content of an object?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I would like to know what would be the most suited method to dump an object content?

So I can have any kind of objects. The example below is just an example and it is derived from `io.Bytes` just to have something to dump that are bytes.

I am clearly wondering whether repurposing the `__str__` method is a good idea or not. Choosing between `to_bytes` or `dump` is more a consensual question and I think `to_bytes` would be more understandable.

#### Use `__str__`:

```
def Foo(io.Bytes):
   def __str__(self):
      self.seek(0)
      return self.read()

foo = Foo()
content = bytes(foo)
```

#### Use method `to_bytes`

```
def Foo(io.Bytes):
   def to_bytes(self):
      self.seek(0)
      return self.read()

foo = Foo()
content = foo.to_bytes()
```

#### Same as above, but with method `dump`

```
foo = Foo()
content = foo.dump()
```

Comment: @martineau I don't understand how the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence-in-python) answers my question.This is not a duplicate.

Comment: OK, but your question is very unclear.

Comment: I propose 3 methods, I ask you to choose one. What is it unclear?

Comment: I could have asked the question differently: is it bad to use `bytes(foo)` to get the bytes content of an object as `__bytes__` does not exists?

Comment: Why do the `__str__` and `to_bytes` methods _read_ and return data?

Comment: What I didn't say is that my object has a binary content. It can be for example a `wave` sound, a `zip-file`, a serialized data written in `xml` or any content that can be dumped into bytes. I would like to know what is the most common name/method to get the binary content out of the object.

Comment: There is no common name or method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127709/discussion-between-nowox-and-martineau).

Comment: I don't have time (or interest) to dwell any further on your question. Another thing I don't understand is why your sample classes are derived from `io.Bytes`, as that makes little sense (_if_ I have any understanding of your question at all). Aside from that, you might want to name the method of your classes `to_bytes()` as that is what [something vaguely similar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) is called for the built-in `int` class in Python 3.2+. Repurposing the `__str__` method name to do what you want is not a good idea, IMO.