# Create an alert for when new content is posted on our website

Tags: email, content-management-system, sitecore, html-email, subscribe

We would like to put a "subscribe" button on our website that people can sign up for. Then, when new content is posted on our site they get an email alert saying new content has been posted. What would be the best way to build this? The website cms is Sitecore.

Not sure where to start. Would I need to do something like this [How can I only send emails when a NEW article is posted to a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194959/how-can-i-only-send-emails-when-a-new-article-is-posted-to-a-webpage)?

Comment: What cms  is it? We can't give a general answer

Comment: it's Sitecore. I'll add this to the post too. Thanks