# Why can't I output a set to a file?

Tags: python, set

Okay so what I'm looking to do is output a set to a file in python.
I have one file, it contains random strings.
I first open the text file and read to check if any duplicates are seen, once finished I want to output the set back to the file.

Here's what I got

```
sets = set()

file1 = open("file1.txt", "r+")
for line in file1:
  sets.add(line)

file1.write(sets)
```

It says that write only takes the argument str and not set.
Anyone know how to get around this?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must convert the set in a suitable string representation, maybe running a for-loop over the set or something simple like `"\n".join(sets)`

Comment: you should really listen to error strings you get, it literally tells you you need it as string, eg file1.write(str(sets))  (or use a proper serializer / deserializer if you want to read it later into a set)

Comment: @RonenNess Yeah mate I know it wants me to convert to a string, but I just wanted to know the most efficient way to do so.

Comment: @poisonishere depends on how you want the output to look. using str(sets) would give something like this 'set([1, 2, 3])', so you might want to use join like Michael proposed. I wouldn't worry about efficiency though, unless you're planning to process really huge files all the time it probably won't matter much.

Comment: I've just tried "\n".join(sets)  and it's worked however it leaves a blank line between each string. Is there any way to keep them line after line?

Comment: You can save them with `pickle` (in Python 3 at least). See [**Saving an Object (Data persistence)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sets = set()

file1 = open("file1.txt", "r+")
for line in file1:
  sets.add(line)

file1.write(repr(sets))
```

Note the use of `repr()`—this will output a Python representation of the object to the file.