# How to access attributes in a python file and save back to file

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.5 and want to store my application configuration in a python file (e.g. settings.py).

### Sample settings.py file

```
ALPHA = 0.1
BETA = {}
```

## Pseudocode

```
import settings as conf

DEFAULT_ALPHA = 0.234
NEW_BETA = { 1: 2, 2: 'Hello'}

keys = [x for x in dir(conf) if x[0] != '_']

if 'ALPHA' not in keys:
    conf.ALPHA = DEFAULT_ALPHA

if 'BETA' not in keys:
    conf.BETA = {}


if not conf.BETA:
    conf.beta = NEW_BETA


# How to write new configuration to file?
```

My question is how I would I then write the new configuration (settings.py) to file?

**[[Addendum]]**

As others have pointed out in the comments section (and even answers), the obvious way to do this would be to use one of the more common "structured data" formats: i.e. JSON, YML, XML etc.

I am aware of the json module (having used it several times in the past). However, I was intrigued by code I saw in a django app which seemed to be directly editing a configuration file (django aficionados would recognise `settings.py`).

I couldn't work out how the settings were being written back to file, and tried to replicate it - hence this question. FWIW, the JSON/YML approach is the obvious one I would have gone for otherwise (have done, several times in the past).

So, my question remains - is there a way to load a python module, modify it and then save it (the module) back to file?

There are actually many scenarios where this would be useful. One such example would be a django app that when installed, actually makes the appropriate changes in settings.py - so there is no need to add the application in `INSTALLED_APPS` variable of `settings.py` and no need to manually add the apps configurations to `settings.py`.

This would aid in deploying new apps in django projects, without having to use current workarounds like different versions of settings.py (for copying over in a Dockerfile for e.g), or even manually having to modify the settings.py file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving an Object (Data persistence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence)

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha I am not a professional developer. I have an IT background (academically, and many moons ago as a developer/consultant), but I don't "do IT" for a living - I'm NOT an IT professional. I work in a completely different domain. I only come on here to ask questions from IT professionals who do this for a living, when I need quick answers on side projects I happen to be working on in my spare time. So now you know!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to not import that configuration file directly but write to functions to load and save the configuration (using json):

```
import json

def loadConfig():
    with open('config.py', 'w+') as configFile:
        try:
            config = json.loads(configFile.read())
        except ValueError:
            config = {}
        except:
            raise
        return config

def saveConfig(config):
    with open('config.py', 'w+') as configFile:
        configFile.write(json.dumps(config))

config = loadConfig()
config["foo"] = "bar"
saveConfig(config)
```

Or just use a ready to use module, which will handle config files for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your settings to be writable, don't make them Python files. Use a text format: .ini is good because it can be read and written using the [`configparser` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) from the standard library.

Another alternative is YAML, which is easy to read and write for both machines and humans.

Comment: `JSON` would be another option, given that `JSON` serialization and deserialization are part of a package typically shipped with standard python installations.

Comment: This is good info, but should not be an answer as it doesn't answer the question, comment would be more suitable.