# How can I save all information of a python class to binary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pickle

I'm creating a little shell app to help me save some info and review some python.

I have a couple of python code for a bunch of classes that refer to each other, such as User, Person, Contact, Event and then a main App.py that I use to test it.

I'm using pickle to save the data, [using this question as inspiration.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence)

My problem is although the class is saved, it's "internal information isn't".

```
import Event
import Contact
import pickle
def saveObj(filename, obj):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(obj,output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    print("SAVED")

def loadObj(filename, obj):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as input:
    obj = pickle.load(input)
    print("LOADED")

p1 = Person.Person("abcd",12,"ui")
p2 = Person.Person("Hah",123,"aaa")
c1 = Contact.Contact([p1,p2], "Wakanda", "12-23-54")
e1 = Event.Event([p1],"12-32-31")
e1.setTitle();
e1.setDescription();

c2 = Contact.Contact([p2],"Forever", "12-23-53")


print("1 for new user, 2 for existing user")
ipt = input("Write something but not exit!\n>>")
filename = ""
while (ipt!= "exit!"):
    if (ipt=="1"):
        print("1")
        idNumber = input("Insert id\n>> ")
        name = input("Inser name\n>> ")
        filename = str(idNumber)+".data"
        session = LoggedIn.User(idNumber,name)
        session.addStuff([e1],[c1,c2],[p1,p2])
        print(session.people)
        saveObj(filename,session)
        del session
    elif(ipt=="2"):
        print("2")
        session = LoggedIn.User(None,None)    
        loadObj(filename,session)
        print(session.people)
    ipt = input("Write something but not exit!\n>>")
```

The return I'd like would be equal to when I use option **1** and option **2**. But instead it's like this:

```
1 for new user, 2 for existing user
Write something but not exit!
>>1
1
Insert id
>> 12345678
Inser name
>> AAA
[<Person.Person object at 0x7fa8079c6908>, <Person.Person object at 0x7fa8079c6940>]
SAVED
Write something but not exit!
>>2
2
LOADED
[]
Write something but not exit!
>>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try the `dill` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj = pickle.load(input)` doesn't change the value of the object you passed in via the `obj` parameter. Try using `return`.

```
def loadObj(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as input:
        obj = pickle.load(input)
    print("LOADED")
    return obj

#later...

print("2")
session = loadObj(filename)
print(session.people)
```

Comment: I feel dumb, somehow I thought I was passing a reference. 
This will serve as a reminder to people that might have had the same problem.. THAT'S NOT A REFERENCE!
(I will thank you very much for the quick response)

Comment: It's a fairly common problem because Python doesn't appear to follow either pass-by-reference or pass-by-value, which many other languages adhere to. In reality it actually _is_ quite close to pass-by-reference: at the beginning of your original function, obj and session are referentially identical, which you can confirm by printing the `id()` of both of them. But the `obj = ...` assignment statement only changes the value of obj, leaving session untouched.