# How to save a loaded module?

Tags: python, module

I got a module `stuff.py` with a lot of unorganized objects.

```
import stuff

myList = getattr(stuff, 'atomsList')
myList.append ('protons')

setattr(stuff, 'atomsList', myList)
```

How do I save the `stuff` module now as `stuff.py`?

Comment: Modules aren't designed as a storage mechanism. You'll have a much cleaner experience if you use a real serialization format and separate data files.

Comment: you might look at the shelve module https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shelve.html

As others pointed out. modules are not intended to be modified by the python code.

It could be done theoretically, but self modifying code is really not a good idea.

To store keyword based data you might look at shelve

if you want to 'transfer' all data existing at the moment in stuff you might write a one shot script, that loops through `stuff` and writse each item into a shelve. afterwards just use the shelve

Comment: Consider storing the data as an instance of a class or as just a dictionary. If you make it a `class`, you can also, optionally, give it methods that operate on the data in it if you wish. See [Saving an Object (Data persistence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence).

Answer (score 0):

The idea with modules I thought is that they are defined in a general sense and are only made specific when they are 'instantiated' in the same way as classes ( and you can't edit the source code). So unless you want to directly edit your class, you should save the instantiated class using pickle.

I think Pickle is what you're looking for...

E.g.:

```
import pickle
import stuff

myList = getattr(stuff, 'atomsList')
myList.append ('protons')
setattr(stuff, 'atomsList', myList)

with open("instantiated_stuff.pickle", ‘wb’) as f:
    pickle.dump(stuff, f)
```

Then to open the file use:

```
with open("instantiated_stuff.pickle", ‘rb’) as pickle_file:
    opend_stuff = pickle.load(pickle_file)
```