# How to resolve pickle encoding?

Tags: python, utf-8, pickle

I am facing an issue with saving my pickle files. I receive the error when I open the pickle file manually:

```
Error: C:\Users\df.pkl is not UTF-8 encoded. Saving disabled. See console for more details.
```

This is what I did for the error to occur:

```
pickle.dump(df, open('df.pkl', 'rb'))
```

and then subsequently:

```
df = pickle.load(open('df.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Comment: Encoding shouldn't matter when writing to a binary file. I think you need to open the file with mode `'wb'` to output to it. See my answer to [Saving an Object (Data persistence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence) for examples of using `pickle`.

Comment: You should be opening the pickle dump file in write mode 'wb'

Comment: I strongly recommend using context managers to handle those file objects!

Comment: I changed the pickle dump file to write mode 'wb' but error persists. I am pickling a dataframe btw, does that affect?

Comment: What does “open the pickle file manually” mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your issue is not coming from encoding of your script:
try by adding at the beginning of your code:

```
#coding: utf-8
```

Maybe another solution can be to use the to_pickle function of pandas (As I think you want to pickle a DataFrame):
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html

To save:

```
df.to_pickle("C:\Users\df.pkl")
```

To load:

```
df = pd.read_pickle("C:\Users\df.pkl")
```