# How can I import a dictionary created by one script into another script?

Tags: python, python-import

I have one python file named `testings.py`, in this file I derive a dictionary by using web scraping of relevant data. To populate the dictionary takes a few minutes.

What I would like to do, instead of copying the whole script into my other python script named `webscraper.py`, and then running the whole of both scripts in effect every time I run `webscraper.py`, is instead import the dictionary from the `testing.py` script into the second script `webscraper.py` and then save myself those minutes everytime I run `webscraper.py`.

Every so often my dictionary will be out of date, in which case I would just run `testings.py` before starting `webcraper.py`. Is there a way to do what I'm asking?

Another thing to note is that, at the start of `testings.py` I have `my_dict = {}` and it's not until the end of the script that `my_dict` is fully populated. So when I import it I want to import the fully populated version of it as if the script had run fully.

Comment: I'm starting to think that this isn't possible, as the testings.py script would need to run to get the my_dict dictionary populated. And my_dict wouldn't be saved anywhere on my pc to import it into webscraper.py. Unless I added some code in testings.py to save the dictionary to a csv file and then in webscraper.py I got it to read the CSV file. Maybe this would be a solution?

Comment: you can pickle the dictionary at whichever state you want and then read the pickle back in later. The pickle knows the object is a dictionary and has all the keys/values in the dictionary as of the time of the pickle dump. Would that achieve what you want?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do what you want. See [Saving an Object (Data persistence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence).

Answer (score 1):

You can either save the dictionary in a number of ways to file (check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html or https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html and how to write files, https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=open) and then read it from the other script.

Or you can just import the scraping script into the other script and call the scraping function from there, returning the result - but that's only a solution if you don't mind running the scraping there and then and you're not looking to reuse the results of an earlier scrape.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this script :

```
from tester import my_dict
print ('Now in second script.')
print (my_dict)
```

It actually runs the script called tester.py and then imports and prints my_dict.

```
my_dict = {}
for x in range (20) :
    for y in range (10) :
        my_dict [x] = y
print (my_dict)
input ('All done now.')
```