# How to save and reuse a function that handle null in python

Tags: python

I have a function that handles any null values for my machine learning project. I would like to know of a way to save a function and reuse it same way I can save a trained machine learning algorithm using pickle and use it on my deployed app backend.

**Function** to save

```
def handle_nulls(df):
    df = df[df['account_status'].notna()]
    
    df = df[df['probability'].notna()]
    
    max = df['am_daysincelast_txn'].max()
    df['am_daysincelast_txn'].fillna(max, inplace=True)
    
    max = df['years_on_net'].max()
    df['years_on_net'].fillna(max, inplace=True)
    
    
    return df
    
df = handle_nulls(df)
```

My way `pickel.dump(handle_null(), open('handle_null.pkl', 'wb'))` doesn't work

Comment: Maybe because it's `pickle` not `pickel`?

Comment: Maybe because it's `handle_null()` not `handle_null`?

Comment: "X doesn't work" isn't really a description that allows us to see what's wrong. Do you get an error? If so please post a stacktrace. Is your output different from what you expected? Then please provide expected output vs. actual output.

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
pickel.dump(handle_null, open('handle_null.pkl', 'wb+'))
```