# Adding data to dictionary in txt file Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, file, dictionary

So i want to doing college project to build some sort of bank application, the input from the user should saved to the dictionary in txt file, but i only know how to do dict in python not the txt file
How should i code this?

my code is something like this

```
    rekening =  {
  
}
a=input("Masukkan Nama Anda :  ")
x = [i for i in range(1, 10)]
norek = (random.choice(x), random.choice(x), random.choice(x))
norekakhir = int(''.join(map(str, norek))) 
rekening[a] = "rek" + str(norekakhir) 
print("Rekening anda dengan nama", a, "Nomer Rekening", "rek" + str(norekakhir))
print("Telah terdaftar")
print("Terima Kasih")
print(rekening)
```

it only save to the dictionary not to txt file, sorry for my broken english and its my first time post here ^^

Comment: Do you really need a flat file? If so, you just output your dict to file in the structure you need. if you need to save your dict for reuse, then you can check this anwser: [Saving an Object (Data persistence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence)

Comment: yeah i just need a flat file, just a name and the number of bank account. Is it the pickle library?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `json.dumps()`

```
import json

my_dict = {
    "a": "x",
    "b": "y"
}

with open("my_dicitonary_file.txt", 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(my_dict))
```

Comment: Sorry, what does json.dumps() do?

Comment: docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps. it converts your dictionary into json formatted str